# Community User can not query FiscalYearsSetting sObject

Tags: apex, lightning

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<FiscalYearSettings> getFiscalYear(){
    List<FiscalYearSettings> fs=[SELECT Id,Name,StartDate,EndDate FROM FiscalYearSettings where StartDate=LAST_N_FISCAL_YEARS:2];
    return fs;
}
```

This work well when log in lightning Experience but when open in lightning community it does not get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the api documentation for this object, customer portal users cannot access this object .

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fiscalyearsettings.htm

You can workaround this by creating a custom object and writing a batch apex to copy over this and use the custom object to feed the lightning component .

Another approach that i have not verified is by creating a wrapper apex class without sharing instead of the actual Object reference .

Comment: Yeah thank for yr answer , I have tried by creating a custom wrapper class and writing a bat apex to copy but it still does not work

Comment: Then batch apex is only way to get going for community users